# FF vs Chrome: cant figure out why my select looks different

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox

This is what it looks like in chrome:

[image: chrome]

This is what it looks like in FF:

[image: firefox]

This is the css I have applied to this element:

```
.styled-select5 {
    margin-left: 20px;
    height: 12px;
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 104px;
    z-index: 1;
    background: url(/images/registration/triangle.png) no-repeat right white;
    display: block;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
    .styled-select5 select {
        padding-right: 42px;
        background: none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        -moz-appearance: none;
        text-indent: .01px;
        text-overflow: '';
        border: none !important;
        width: 110% !important;
        overflow: hidden;
        z-index: 5;
        height: 14px;
        display: block;
        padding-left: 3px;}
    .styled-select5 select::-ms-expand{
       display: none;}
        .styled-select5 select option {
            height: 20px;
            width: 400px; }
    .styled-select5.hidden {
        display: none; }
```

I have been trying to figure this out for a while.  In order for them to look similar I have to change the padding in FF to get the text to show properly.  I am not sure why this is happening.  Is there some difference in the way chrome and FF do this?

Comment: Have you tried to set `line-height`?

Comment: I do not think that has anything to do with the text getting cut off.

Comment: I don't think you explained the problem in your question, that's why I thought you want the text in the middle.

Comment: Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. See http://SSCCE.org for guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Each browser (on every OS) displays the HTML elements differently. The amount of styling that can override the defaults is also decided by the browser.
You cannot edit beyond what's permitted. If you happen to use selects for Safari, it'll look far more different and you cannot customize much there as well.